# where does GWT compiled output get saved in IntelliJ

Tags: cordova, gwt, intellij-idea

I am building my first GWT phonegap application .
As per the document, I need to put the compiled out put (i.e the folder with the same name as of my project name inside war folder) to My Android project's www folder.

I did this and it all Ok for Eclipse.

Now i need to do the same for IntelliJ, But when i compile I dont see that folder(with the same name as of my project folder inside war folder)..

What folder incase of IntelliJ Project I need to put in My Android project's www folder.

Answer (score 0):

`~/.IntelliJIdea14/system/gwt/<project and id>/<module and id>/run`

The "project and id" will look something like "Foo.e1b4d1e7"; similarly the "module and id".

Answer (score 0):

Build an artifact (Project Settings -> Artifacts)  https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/artifact.html

Pick which parts of your project output (shows on the right panel) you want to be copied at specific folder (define it at the top). Then you will be able to avoid copying extra content (if there's any extras).